# SQL to show all Key IDs that fail to meet critieria for all records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table with 4 columns that store entries for the different states that a 'page' goes through in my application:

```
Id | PageId | State | TimeStamp
```

`Id` is unique, `PageId` is a GUID that is unique to a page, `State` is one of four of the following:

```
QUEUED
REQUESTED
PUBLISHED
COMMITTED
```

and `TimeStamp` is a `datetime`

Under successful conditions, there are four entries in the database for each `PageId`: one for each state that it goes through, in the order written above.

I want to write a query that would give me all pages that DON'T have a COMMITTED state.  I am using SQL Server. I'm not sure how to write the query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to show each `PageID` that does not have a record where `State=COMMITTED`.  Is this correct?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but why not add a column in your "Page" table that stores the current State? Then you can write a much simpler query on that table and join it with the table described in your question. It will be much a much more efficient query.

Comment: And if you take @mdkirby's suggestion you could use an update trigger to maintain the history of previous states potentially.

Comment: @mdkirby That is a good idea.  I'll look into it tomorrow when I'm at work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility

```
SELECT PageId 
FROM   YourTable 
GROUP  BY PageId 
HAVING Count(CASE 
               WHEN State = 'Committed' THEN 1 
             END) = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want every row from those `PageId`s:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.YourTable
                  WHERE PageId = A.PageId
                  AND [State] = 'COMMITTED')
```

If you only want the PageId:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.PageId
FROM dbo.YourTable A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.YourTable
                  WHERE PageId = A.PageId
                  AND [State] = 'COMMITTED')
```